# JQuery: How to add a class to nested elements, one by one?

Tags: jquery, html, list, menu, nested

Ok, I'm creating a multilevel menu, when one sub-menu is open all the others are closed, except if the sub-menu has another sub-menu nested to it, in this case all the others sub-menus are closed except for the parent and the current sub-menu.

I do the trick with this code:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
 $('li').not(this).each(function(){
  $(this).find('ul').removeClass('red');
 });
 $(this).find('ul').addClass('red');
});
```

On this example use just a color change for demostration purposes, but the problem is the same, click one <**li**> element and change the color to the next <**ul**> children. My code doesn't work very well, on click change to red all the nested <**ul**>. What's the problem? Help please, thanks in advance.

**Problem example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/EddyRocket/ttkqqd64/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem there is that when you do `$('li').on(...)`, you are creating an event handler for each `li`. So when you click on a sub level, it also triggers the click event on all parent li's.

You could have one event on the main `ul`, and handle everything from a single function:

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(e){
    // get clicked item
    var clickedItem = $(e.target).closest('li')[0];
    // remove all active classes
    $('.menu ul').removeClass('red')
    // find the ul inside the clicked item
    .filter(function(_index, _ul){
        return $.contains(clickedItem, _ul);
    })
    // add active class
    .addClass('red');
});
```

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ttkqqd64/2/

Comment: Wow man! This is beautiful! Perfectly solution for the problem! Just two questions about the code. Fisrt, .closest('li')[0] it's equal to .closest('li').get(0) and second, _index, _ul what's the meaning of the underscores? Thanks in advance and thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: Glad it helped. So, yes, jQuery `get(0)` equals array notation `[0]`. And the underscore, doesn't have any semantic value, it is just a convention, traditionally used to identify private methods (which is not the case here), but that also depends on the design pattern you are using. I, personally, use it to differentiate variables declared a level deeper in the scope, so if I had, for example, another event handler nested there, I'd declare the event object as `_e`, as opposed to `e` in the first level. But again, that is very much a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Use stopPropagation to stop the parent li's from receiving the click event.  Then only apply the red class to sibling li's.

```
$('li').on('click', function(ev){
 ev.preventDefault();
 ev.stopPropagation();
 $(this).siblings().find('ul').removeClass('red');
 $(this).find('ul').addClass('red');
});
```